# Getting the maximum value of a value in an Entity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to get the maximum value for an attribute in an Entity in core data.  Apple has a nice example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) of how to do this; however, it doesn't work for me.  I have 10 objects in my moc and the following code always returns an array of size 0.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
  NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

  // set the idx to the maximum value
  NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" 
                                            inManagedObjectContext:moc];
  [request setEntity:entity];

  // Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
  [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

  // Create an expression for the key path.
  NSExpression* keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"idx"];

  // Create an expression to represent the minimum value at the key path 'creationDate'
  NSExpression* maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" 
                                                          arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

  // Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
  NSExpressionDescription* expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

  // The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
  [expressionDescription setName:@"maxIdx"];
  [expressionDescription setExpression:maxExpression];
  [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

  // Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
  [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

  // Execute the fetch.
  NSError* error = nil;
  NSArray* objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
  }
  else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
      int newIdx = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxIdx"] intValue] + 1;
      [self setPrimitiveIdx:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newIdx]];
    } else {
      [self setPrimitiveIdx:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right to me, so check the following

1. You actually have Transaction objects in your store.  Just do a normal fetch from the same context.
2. Could you be doing this before you set up the context?
3. Check to see if there's anything in error -- just log `[error localDescription]`
4. Is NSInteger32AttributeType right for idx?
5. Is idx spelled correctly? Is Transaction?  Meaning, they match your model.

PS: It won't matter for the result, but hopefully you have the releases from the code sample

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I think the most likely error is misspelling `Transaction` or the keypath. I would run the fetch without the expression and see what you get back.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked spelling and other things several times.  There are 10 Transaction objects in the store and idx is an Integer 32.  I'm using garbage collection in the app so the releases shouldn't matter.  I'll check the error log.

Comment: It appears that the above will work once the persistent store has been saved; but not before that.  I was able to get around using it altogether within an alternative solution though.

Comment: Good point.  Yes -- this kind of request is done against the store.